# How to resolve Karabiner key conflict?

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder, shortcut, karabiner

I have the following rule to open Finder with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, but typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> also opens Finder. How can I open Finder with only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and no other key?

```json
{
  "description": "Open Finder",
  "manipulators": [
    {
      "from": {
        "key_code": "f",
        "modifiers": {
          "mandatory": ["left_control"]
        }
      },
      "to": [
        {
          "shell_command": "open -a Finder"
        }
      ],
      "type": "basic"
    }
  ]
}
```